# Know when value of any variable defined inside the class is changed

Tags: java, pojo

I have defined a class which acts like a model/pojo. The class has many keys/variable. I have implemented custom solution for storing the POJO on disk for future uses. Now what I want to do is that whenever any value in the class/POJO is changed, I should call a method which sync the fresh changes with file on disk.

I know I can define setter for each variable. But it's quite tedious to do for 100s of direct and sub fields, and even if I define setter for each field, I have to call sync function from all the setters.

What I need is single proxy setter or interceptor for all change pushes to variables in class.

I am using this in an android application, so whenever the user enters new details in his/her account I have to store those details at that specific instance of time for preventing the data loss. I am using GSON for serialising and de-serialising.

Sorry for using vague terminologies, never been to college :|.

Comment: Eclipse gives you opportunity to add setters for your fields with 3 or 4 clicks. Worth trying. (Source->Add Setters/Getters). But for your sync method I don't how you can achieve what you are asking

Comment: How is the POJO updated if there are no setter methods?  Are you sure you want to write to disk when a single field is updated?  So for example, 5 fields are updated, there would be 5 disk writes?

Comment: Check out Aspect-Oriented Programming, in particular AspectJ. You an define a pointcut across all your setters and attach and advice that does your syncing-to-disk logic, after the underling variable is changed. http://www.baeldung.com/aspectj

Comment: @AndrewS I am using this in an android application, so whenever the user enters new details his/her account I have to store those details at that specific instance. I using GSON for serialising and deserialising.

Comment: Why when a single field is updated?  Why not when the user clicks a Save button, or when Activity.stop()/destroy() is invoked?

Comment: Right now already doing the onCLick thing, and thanks for suggesting actvity onClick/onDestroy will try that. The onClick thing is adding complexity as the profile properties are increasing. But this onDestroy way is awesome if the calling of onDestroy is guaranteed except in the case of sudden power off or system crash.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is indeed to use a setter. You only have to create one for each field you want to monitor, and most IDEs generate them for you or you can use something like Koloboke, so it being tedious isn't really an argument.

A proxy class or reflection would also be possible, but that is pretty hacky. Another way would be an asynchronous watcher/worker that checks for changes in you POJO instances, but even that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Apart from that you might need to rethink your POJOs structure if it has that many fields.

Comment: Brother, there is meta field under the POJO, and in meta field there alot of sub feild, and i can't reduce them, they are all required.

Comment: You could reduce the number of fields by splitting it into multiple subobjects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with persisting(in your case writting to a disk) entity on each property update is that most of the updates are modifying more then one property. So in case you have a code like this:

```
entity.setA(avalue);
entity.setb(bvalue);
entity.setc(cvalue);
```

You would write it to the disk 3 times, which is probably not a best way, as it takes more resources, and 2 out of 3 writes are unnecessary.

There are several ways to deal with it. Imagine you have some service for saving this data to a disk, lets name it `entityRepository`. So one option is manually call this `entityRepository` each time you want to save/update your entity. It seems to be very uncomfortable, comparing to calling this automatically on setter call, however, this approach clearly shows you when and why your entity is persisted/updated, in your approach it's unclear, and can lead to some problems future problems and mistakes, for example, in future you will decide that you now need to update one of the properties without immideately persisting, then it appears that you will need 2 setter, one with update, and one without...

Another way is to add `version` property, and when its setter is called inside this setter call `entityRepository.save(this)`.

The other way is to look at [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), however anyway I don't recommend persist entity on any change, without having control over it.

Comment: Getting you dude, and right now I am already using the first approach, calling the service right after updating the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about data binding. There is no built-in way for that so you have indeed to sync it yourself. Look into [How to Write a Property Change Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). There are also lots of other approaches to this, but as said no built-in way.